# How can I reorganize a structure that's organized by time in MATLAB?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, sorting

suppose I have data of various items (x) at discrete time events (t1 ... tn), organized in a structure S. The fields of the structure are of the form:

`S.t1.x = x(t1)`
`S.t2.x = x(t2)`
...
`S.tn.x = x(tn)`, etc.

where each subfield has only one value from the whole x

How best could I rearrange this into a structure of the form

`S.x = x(t1 ... tn)`?

For now I am looping through each time field and assigning the corresponding variable to the appropriate time index in a different structure, as in

```
for i = 1:length(t)

X(i) = S.(t(i)).x;
Y(i) = S.(t(i)).y;

end
```

with some vectorization so I don't actually have to assign each individual variable.

This gets the results I need, but since there is over a gigabyte of data to convert, it takes a while and I'd like to make this as efficient as possible. Is there an algorithm for doing this any better?

Comment: That's an unfortunate way to organize data. You can use [`struct2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html), but the output order depends on the order in which the struct was created, not the numerical order of the field names. Your loop is likely the best method. Run it once and save the result so you don't have to convert the data again. If you make new data in the unfortunate format, I suggest you change that code instead.

Comment: Umnfortunately, I did not create the data, I am given it to use. Thank you still

Comment: Considering it's a gigabyte of data, changing how it is stored would make a huge difference. Scalar values in a struct use up something like 114 bytes each, compared to 8 bytes each if they're in a numeric array. That's 14 times as many bytes!

Comment: That's part of the reason. For one, I need the data as an array as a function of time, and I also only need a small fraction of the variables that are actually in the each time state. Processing the data down to a reasonable size takes so much longer than what I am actually doing with the data!

Comment: Are you preallocating the output arrays? That's the most important thing to make code fast. Loops in MATLAB are not inherently slow, it is the indexing you do inside the loop that probably takes most time. I don't think that vectorization, if there's a possibility for it, would speed things up a lot.

Comment: I'm profiling the code now to identify choke points. The output arrays do end up preallocated after the first pass of the loop once the size of each variable is known.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243596/discussion-between-robbie-crockett-and-cris-luengo).

Comment: If your S.t is an array of struct, `Snew.x= [S.t.x]; Snew.y= [S.t.y];` should work. I don't know whether it is any faster.